# Javascript alert.window is not working on my github page

Tags: javascript, jquery, github

I am new to the developer world and currently working on a online course in web design and Python. So excuse me if my question is vague or stupid ;-)

Im am working on a simple assignment where I need to add a jQuery application in my code. I created a very simple code where it should open a alert window. The code looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#verzend").click(function() {
          var naam = $("#naam").val();
          var leeftijd = $("#leeftijd").val();
          var woonplaats = $("#woonplaats").val();
          var hobby = $("#hobby").val();
          window.alert(
          "Hallo " + naam +
          " van " + leeftijd +
          " jaar oud! Wat leuk dat jij in " + woonplaats +
          " woont en jouw " + hobby + " is. Groetjes, Jeffrey");
        });
      });
    </script>
```

When I open the html file in Chrome directly from the folder on my laptop the alert window works. But I have the exact same code in a online github page, but there the alert window won't show when i visit the page via Chrome. The teachers of the online course aren't really helping me and say that there must be a fault in the filepath. But then it wouldn't be working in the html file as well, right? I have no clue what the problem is here, so hopefully someone can help.
The github page can be found here: https://jeffreykrab.github.io/huiswerkles25/

Thanks!

I wrote a code for a alert window using jquery. I opened the file with Chrome and the alert window is working as expected. Then i uploaded the html file to github and published the page. When i open the page via the github link the alert window is not working any more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue might be because you are not using `https` when you link the jquery library in your head.

When I open the site you host on github pages and check network tab in dev tools, it shows that jquery failed to load `blocked:mixed-content`

[image]

Jquery will not work if it is not loaded :)

Comment: This fixed the issue. I knew it had to be something simple, but didn't think of this. Thank you!